# "Hide Content Show Content" Image Hover

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I've got an button that on page load reads "Show Content", and when clicked, the content is shown and it switches to a button with "Hide Content". This works nicely, as per my code below.

```
$('div.content').hide();
    
$('img.contentslide').click(function() {
    $('div.content').toggle(1500,function() {
        if (jQuery.browser.msie) {                          // Lines 15-17 = special treatment for IE, because of  
            this.style.removeAttribute('filter');           // lack of support for ClearType font rendering on items
        }                                                   // being toggled in jQuery.
    });
        if (slideState == 'closed') {
            $('img.contentslide').attr('src','images/hidecontentstd.png');
            slideState = "open";    

        } else {
            $('img.contentslide').attr('src','images/showcontentstd.png');
            slideState = "closed";
        }
});
```

with slideState being my boolean variable that is set to closed on DOM ready.

What I AM having problems with is getting a hover in there, so that when the user hovers over the button the RELEVANT hover image appears (i.e. a hide content hover when slideState is open and a show content hover when slideState is closed).

I've tried following this: http://www.foryourlungsonly.net/2007/10/jquery-image-swap/

But with no luck. I don't want to use CSS hovers, please.

Comment: Why can't you use the same technique you use with `.click()` (choose the picture depending on the value of `slideState`)?

Comment: @Juhana, Because I know very little jQuery (being a 15 yo student and all...) and I really wouldn't have the faintest clue as to how to implement it. I've tried a few ways and they haven't worked, and no tutorials I've seen seem to address my particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do the same thing you do when you select the correct image with `.click()` but with a `.hover()` event instead.

```
$('img.contentslide').hover( function() {
        if (slideState == 'closed') {
            $( this ).attr('src','images/closedHover.png');
        } else {
            $( this ).attr('src','images/openHover.png');
        }
    },
    function() {
        if (slideState == 'closed') {
            $( this ).attr('src','images/closedNoHover.png');
        } else {
            $( this ).attr('src','images/openNoHover.png');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks. For the time being I've copied and pasted, and changed the relevant images sources, but I'm going to attempt to understand how it works. Once again, thank you.